# Error al realizar consulta en javaFx a travez de sentencias sql

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

Pues tengo el problema de que quiero obtener los registros de un simple select * from tabla, pero me dice que no obtiene ningún registro

El codigo de la consulta

```
ConexionBD("eduware", "root", "", "3306");
        Conexion();
                this.conexion = Conexion();
                if(this.conexion!=null){
                    this.stmt = this.conexion.createStatement();
                    rs=this.stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM alumno");
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,rs.getRow());
                    if(rs.getRow()!=0){
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Ejecutada Con Exito");
                    }
                    else{
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Ejecutada Sin Exito");
                    }
```

Hace todo excepto al momento de la condición if, ya que en ese momento se va por la parte de que no se ha echo la consulta con éxito y el mensaje del rs.getRow es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así que también puse un mensaje para ver si se había conectado a la base de datos y me marco lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla si contiene informacion y datos alrededor de 6 registros completos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es necesario mover el cursor del `ResultSet` al final para obtener el número de filas devueltas por la consulta

```
ConexionBD("eduware", "root", "", "3306");
    Conexion();
            this.conexion = Conexion();
            if(this.conexion!=null){
                this.stmt = this.conexion.createStatement();
                rs=this.stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM alumno");
                rs.last();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,rs.getRow());
                 /* Return Numero Fila Actual. 
                 como movimos antes al final, será igual al total */
                if(rs.getRow()!=0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Ejecutada Con Exito");
                  /* Para mover el cursor al Inicio en el caso que 
                   querramos trabajar con los datos devueltos */
                  rs.beforeFirst();
                }
                else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," Ejecutada Sin Exito");
                }
```